# How can I elegantly request Google Classroom api access through Google Sign-In on android?

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-signin, google-classroom

I am developing an android app that includes functionality for interaction between Google Classroom and Google Drive. The problem is, it seems that the Google Classroom API is fairly limited and not yet well integrated with other Google APIs.

I want to request Google Classroom access through Google Sign-In (where I am also requesting Google Drive access). Is there a simple way to do this all-in-one, and if so, how?

See code below to better understand.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            // *HERE* is where I want to request Classroom SCOPES
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API, 
    // Google Dirve API, Google Classroom API, and options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            // *HERE* is where I want to add the API .addApi(Classroom.API)
            .build();
```

Comment: I think what you are doing right now is correct. Just follow the instructions/guidelines that you will find in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) on how to Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App. Just take note that you also need to follow the guides [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).

Comment: I have been following that documentation, and it works perfectly for Google Drive. My issue is with Google Classroom because it seems that it is not well integrated with Google Sign-In.